# How to calculate the number of iteration when using double nested forEach in Mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have the following query that I need to execute:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function (doc) { doc.records.forEach(function (record) { if (record.user.email.includes("example.com") || record.user.email.includes("example.co.uk")) { record.user.internal =  true; } else { record.user.internal = false }}); db.collection.save(doc); });
```

As it's a double nested forEach loop, is there a way to calculate how many iteration it will to loop through all `records` in all documents in the database? I tried using `count()` but it doesn't seem to work with `forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

The mongo shell support javascript, so you can introduce a variable and increment it in the loop.

```
var count=0  //variable to hold the number of iterations.
db.collection.find({

}).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.records.forEach(function(record){
        if(record.user.email.includes("example.com")||record.user.email.includes("example.co.uk")){
            record.user.internal=true;
        }else{
            record.user.internal=false
        }
    });
    db.collection.save(doc);
    count++;
});
print(count)
```